# How to dispay an image on ajax call

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I have created a user search engine , that displays the user's details  and I would like also to display their profile picture.

index.php

```
if (account !="") {
$.ajax({
    url:"profile.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
        number:account,
    },
    dataType:"JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#image").html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
        $("#name").text(data.name);
        $("#phone").text(data.phone);
        $("#email").text(data.email);
    },
    error: function(err) {    
        alert("Result is not found");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please do not add such a bunch of code in a comment. Instead, edit your question and add the code there. Besides that, what exactly is your problem? You told us what you want to do, but you actually did not ask a question.

Comment: your #image line in the success method calls the data object and not what I assume would be the data.image property?  As a result you are likely not getting the image but rather you are trying to insert the entire data object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(data) {
                                    return '<img src="'+data+'" class = "img-circle" hight = "50" width = "50" />';
                                    }                           

After fetching you data please update the render function to put you image property in that function
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this

```
$("p").html('<img src="' + data.image + '" />');
```

Thanks.